# Ordering Gallery images by custom order

Tags: c#, strings, array, image

I wrote some code a few weeks ago, to take a string similar to

> seq[]=8&seq[]=7&seq[]=5&seq[]=1&seq[]=4&seq[]=3&seq[]=6&seq[]=0&seq[]=2

and put it into a gallery, to be ordered by jQuery UI's Sortable, which works all good, however, I'm concerned about the amount of times I `.Replace` the values in the string.

This code has been [bugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun) me, because I'm employed to rewrite unethical code, and the few times I actually write code from scratch, it looks like this. So, basically, I would love [your](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) opinions on this code.

To clarify, the `imgMgr` is to get the JSON string, and the `nodelist` is for getting an XML doc of images from the `imgMgr`.

```
#region BuildGallery
private void BuildGallery()
{

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append("<div class=\"controls\"><center><button class=\"js-serialize\" style=\"border: 0;height: 25px;background-color: #F4FA58;margin-bottom: 8px;\">Save Layout</button></center></div><div class=\"sortable\"><ul id=\"sortable\">");
    int pos = 0;
    string str = "";
    ImageManagerV1 imgMgr = new ImageManagerV1();
    str = imgMgr.galleryOrder(LocalConfig.ImageManagerAuthCode, Convert.ToInt32(hdnListingId.Value), "");
  //  str = "seq[]=8&seq[]=7&seq[]=5&seq[]=1&seq[]=4&seq[]=3&seq[]=6&seq[]=0&seq[]=2";
    str.Replace("seq[]=","-").Split('-');
    XmlNodeList nodelist = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("image");
    str = str.Replace("&", "");
    if (str == "") {
        for (int i = 0; i < nodelist.Count; i++) {
            str += "seq[]=" + i;
        }
    }
    string[] strNew = str.Replace("seq[]=", "-").Split('-');
        str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < strNew.Length; i++) {
            if (strNew[i] != "") {
                str += "-" + strNew[i];
            }
        }
    if (nodelist.Count > strNew.Length) {
        for (int f = strNew.Length; f < nodelist.Count; f++) {
            str += "-" + f;
        }
    }
    int val2 = 0;
    string[] stringArray = str.Split('-');
    foreach (string num in stringArray) {
        var newNum = num.ToString();
        if (newNum.Length > 0) {
            val2 = Convert.ToInt32(newNum);
            XmlNode image = nodelist[val2];
            string thumbpath = image.Attributes["thumb"].Value;
            string detailpath = image.Attributes["detail"].Value;
            string fileName = detailpath.Substring(detailpath.LastIndexOf(@"/") + 1);
            sb.AppendFormat("<li class=\"thumb ui-state-default\" id=\"seq_{0}\">", val2);
            sb.AppendFormat("<img src=\"{0}\" alt=\"{2}\" title=\"Gallery: {2}\" width=\"90\" height=\"90\"/><a href=\"\" data=\"{4}\"class=\"makeHero\">Make Hero</a><a href=\"\" data=\"{4}\"class=\"deleteImage\">Del</a>", thumbpath, detailpath, listing.ListingName, pos, fileName);
            sb.Append("</li>");
        }
    }
    sb.Append("</ul><div class=\"clear\"></div></div>");
        if (sb.Length > 0)
        {
            litGallery.Text = string.Format("<div id=\"listing-gallery\" class=\"listing-gallery\">{0}</div>", sb.ToString());
        }
    }
#endregion
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> string str = "";
> ```

There's no sense in assigning `str` to an empty string just to over write it two lines later. This would be much more terse.

```
ImageManagerV1 imgMgr = new ImageManagerV1();
string str = imgMgr.galleryOrder(LocalConfig.ImageManagerAuthCode, Convert.ToInt32(hdnListingId.Value), "");
```

---

> ```
> str.Replace("seq[]=","-").Split('-');
> ```

Why not just split on `"seq[]="`? The Replace feels unnecessary here. Actually, the more I look at this, why are you *splitting*? [Split returns an array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but you're not making an assignment here. I really think you need to decide what this line is supposed to do.

> ```
> str = str.Replace("&", "");
> if (str == "") {
>     for (int i = 0; i < nodelist.Count; i++) {
>         str += "seq[]=" + i;
>     }
> }
> ```

Two things. As a maintainer of the code, I've no idea why you're stripping out the ampersands. A comment here is in order. Secondly, this loop needs a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). StringBuilder is a *mutable* string of characters and thus, more efficient in this situation.

> ```
> string[] strNew = str.Replace("seq[]=", "-").Split('-');
> ```

Okay, now you can skip the Replace and split directly on `"seq[]="`. Speaking of, that string seems to show up an awful lot. You should replace it with a constant.

```
string[] separators = new string[] {"seq[]="};
strNew = str.Split(separators, SplitStringOptions.None);
```

> ```
>     for (int i = 0; i < strNew.Length; i++) {
>         if (strNew[i] != "") {
>             str += "-" + strNew[i];
> ```

At first glance, I want to tell you to use a string builder again, but I honestly don't have the foggiest idea why you just split the string apart, just to put it back together. Forget what I just said about splitting, and just `Replace("seq[]=","-")`. Don't split. It looks to be unecessary.

Comment: @Quill for iterative reviews, it is recommended that you post your updated code as a new question. More people will see it that way.

Comment: I'm just not going to have time to come back to this, but here's the IDEOne I was working on. It should give you an idea of where I was heading. http://ideone.com/OWz2oP

Answer (score 2):

- you should make this method independent from any UI element like `litGallery`. In this way you are decoupling your code from UI dependencies.
- instead of using the not commented class variable `xmlDoc` you should have passed it as input parameter.
- your method should take a `String` and a `XmlDocument` input parameter and should return a `String` representing the `html` of the gallery.
- by extracting these loooooong html strings like `"<div class=\"controls\"><center><button class=\"js-serialize\" style=\"bord.......` into meaningful constants the code building the gallery will be more readable.
- the whole method should be broken into multiple methods which should

  - preparing the `str`
  - building the html
- most C# developers like me prefer to assign `String.Empty` over `""`
- you should be consistent with the coding style you use. If you place the opening brace `{` at the same line with the `if` condition` you should stick to it.
- the check fo `if (sb.Length > 0)` is not necessary and can be removed
- calling `ToString()` on a `String` is not necessary
- the `newNum` variable is not necessary and can be removed. You should just use `num` variable
- the whole building of this string should be done using a `List<T>` instead of adding, replacing and splitting these strings.

Comment: You just saved me a ton of time.